# Python 2.6.6 Ubuntu Server os.environ not unicode

Tags: python, apache, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to write a simple chat system that accepts various languages and translates them automatically, printing both the original language and a second language (e.g, English) next to it.

But, I've encountered no end of problems, and the reason, I think, is because Python reads os.environ as a byte string, in ASCII, and not Unicode. I need to be able to retrieve the QUERY STRING environment variable from Apache in unicode, utf-8 so I can actually get the text in different character sets. Right now, they all show up as ?s.

Is there anyway I can change this, so python can read os.environ in unicode? Is it a problem with Apache, Linux or Python itself? I've been searching google for several hours now, and most of the answers are regarding python 3, which I'm hesitant to upgrade to (but will if there is no other choice).

I have Apache override all character sets to utf-8, so all my pages are forced that way.

This is my extremely simple test HTML:

```
<form action=exec/post.py method=post><input type=text name='a'><input type=submit></form>
```

And this is the post.py it calls:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import urllib2

print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
print
for key,value in os.environ.items():
        print key + ":"+ str(type(value))
```

Then, if you look at the source of the output, it will show the type as str, not unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to upgrade to Python 3 just for this. You need to decode the strings to get Unicode values. This will show that all the values are now `unicode`:

```
for key,value in os.environ.items():
    print key + ":"+ str(type(value.decode("utf-8")))
```

Comment: Hmmm... so, you are right. It took me a while to realize it, because for some reason, if you type the URI (well, IRI) explicitly, it still comes up as ???, but if I submit the form, it does indeed get converted into Unicode. 
Chrome Browser will let me type it explicitly, but IE and Opera do not. Any idea why? The reason its strange is I can go to Google Translate and type in the different characters just fine in the IRI, and it works there. It's not needed functionality, but it would be nice!

Comment: @Keozon I understand you to be asking about question marks appearing in the *browser's field* when you type in the URI. If I understood correctly, then this is a browser issue, and not a Python one. It probably also depends on your OS because language support is usually provided to applications by the OS.

Comment: No, I mean if I remove the type() and just view the actual value, when I submit via the form, it is fine, but if I type it in the browser bar, (e.g, post.py?a=текст) it will show up as ???, but only in some browsers. If I got to google and do that same thing, all browsers work there (e.g, http://translate.google.com/#ru/en/текст)

Comment: @Keozon When you check the value of ``a`` in your code is it a ``str`` or ``unicode`` type? Does it vary on a per-browser basis?

Answer (score 0):

`os.environ` is **always** bytes only, as are URLs and query strings.

You need to decode such information in your own code:

```
print u'{0}: {}'.format(key, value.decode('utf8'))
```

This is fundamental to how streams (network connections, files, pipes, etc.) work; they always contain bytes. Those bytes can be interpreted in different ways, if you they contain Unicode values, you need to explicitly decode them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried that already, but I did it again, and copied you to make sure I didn't miss anything. I am still getting ????? instead of текст.

Comment: Sorry, you were right. See explanation/question in Louis' answer.

Comment: Note that this works both ways; sending back to the browser requires you to encode again.